# Scala equivalent to Python returning multiple items

Tags: python, scala

In Python it's possible to do something like this:

```
def blarg():
    return "blargidy", "blarg"

i, j = blargh()
```

Is there something similar available in scala?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can return a tuple:

```
def blarg = ("blargidy", "blarg")

val (i, j) = blarg
```

Note the pattern-matching syntax for parallel variable assignment: this works for any pattern, not just for tuples. So for instance:

```
val list = 1 :: 2 :: 3 :: Nil

val x :: y = list // x = 1 and y = 2 :: 3 :: Nil
```

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, only if the number of elements returned match the number of variables. Otherwise you get the error "too many values to unpack", which is what you would get in Python on the second example.

Comment: Ah, I see... in Scala you get the rest of the cons-list in the last variable. In Python 3.x you can do this with a `*` on the last variable, IIRC.

Comment: this is *different* than python: in the latter the returned elements are *variables*.  So we can not do . `var s1 =.. ;  var s2 = ..   var (s1,s2) = someMethod()`

Answer (score 6):

I realize this is an old question, but there's another way to achieve the same. I don't know if there's any downside to it, but the advantage is that the values returned are "named", making the code a little more self-explanatory.

(tested on scala 2.11)

```
package test.scala.misc

object TestReturnMultipleNamedValues extends App {

    val s = getMultipleNamedValues

    println(s"changed=${s.dsChanged} level=${s.dsLevel}")

    /** Returns an anonymous structure with named members.
     * */
    def getMultipleNamedValues() : {val dsChanged : Boolean;val dsLevel : Int} = {
        new {
            val dsChanged = true
            val dsLevel = 1
        }
    }
}
```